# Put checkbox values into hidden input with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms

I'd like to populate a hidden input with the values of selected checkboxes with a space between these values. I've tried the following which in theory should work but it isnt…

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


      var vals = $(':checkbox:checked').map(function(){
         return $(this).val();
      }).get().join(',');

      // save the values to a hidden field
      $('#tags').val(vals);


});
```

HTML

```
 <form>

  <input type="checkbox" value="test1" id="test1"><label>Test</label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="test2" id="test2"><label>Test2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="test3" id="test3"><label>Test3</label>

  <input type="text" value="" id="tags">

</form>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: it work just fine http://jsfiddle.net/vysZd/

Comment: Seems to work for me to : http://jsfiddle.net/96qfB/ are you trying to update the result when a checkbox is changed as well ?

Comment: Your code is working fine, see here -> https://tinker.io/4384e

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`:checkbox` is deprecated

Instead of

```
$(':checkbox:checked')
```

Use

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')
```

Also none of the `checkboxes are checked` when the `document is Ready` .. Set them first and then try ...

**HTML**

```
  <input type="checkbox" value="test1" id="test1" checked><label>Test</label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="test2" id="test2" checked><label>Test2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="test3" id="test3"><label>Test3</label>
  <input type="text" value="" id="tags">
```

**Javascript**

```
function Populate(){
    vals = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get().join(',');
    console.log(vals);
    $('#tags').val(vals);
}

$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    Populate()
}).change();
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/YANTh/1/)**

Comment: Thanks so much, this works exactly as I wanted! stupid me for running it on document ready :@!

Comment: @Nick.. Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 3):

You just need to change your selector and attach your script to some event. For example:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {

    var vals = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get().join(',');

    $('#tags').val(vals);

});​
```

See this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DfsUm/1/).