# Keeping jQuery addClass when going back in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, addclass, toggleclass

I'm having some trouble understanding how to turn my addClass into a cookie. I have a multi-select box that currently filters a list of products by adding an active class and then only showing products with the specified tags. If you make a selection and then click one of the products to view the product and then go back you have to reselect the previously selected options again. Below is the code used to make the selection.

```
        tabsBlock.children('.tab').click(function() {
        var tabContentClass = $(this).attr('id') + '-content';
        tabsBlock.children('.active').removeClass('active');
        tabsContentBlock.children('.active').removeClass('active').hide();
        $(this).addClass('active');
        if (tabContentClass.length) {
            tabsContentBlock.children('#' + tabContentClass).addClass('active').show();
        }
        getTags();
    });
```

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Try reading [about cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)

Comment: Back as in clicking the back button or by clicking a link you have provided?

Comment: back as in clicking the back button on the browser after clicking on a link from this page

Comment: Could you provide a more or less working fiddle reproducing the problem? that would help a lot. But if I'm not mistaken you could save it to the *localStorage* (`localStorage.setItem('key', 'someValue')`) and then loading that info (`localStorage.getItem('key')`) and doing some process with it.

Comment: Check out this link http://hibbard.eu/how-to-persist-checkbox-checked-state-after-page-reload/

Answer (score 0):

For a case like you describe I would would use hidden inputs.  See this example:

[Put checkbox values into hidden input with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292607/put-checkbox-values-into-hidden-input-with-jquery)

Reason being, it sounds like you only need to store the values for this particular case.  Storing in a cookie will require you to manage when the cookie expires which can be messy and cause undesired behaviors.

I don't know much about localStorage (as mentioned in the comment) -- that may be a viable option as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help. I ended up using [Astaroth's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4314631/astaroth) suggestion of using local storage.

```
$(".tag-group-label").click(function(){
        localStorage.setItem('tagGroupLabelState', 'open');
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){   
        if(localStorage.getItem('tagGroupLabelState') == 'open') {
            $('.tag-group-label').addClass('open').next('.tag-container').slideToggle(400, function(){
                reCalcStickyElement();
            });
        }
    });
```