# How to Access this.sameFormFieldsAsArray values

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

In my Application.cfc file I set `this.sameFormFieldsAsArray = True`.

When I dump the form I see the values in the array. How do I access them now if I want to loop through them and do other actions?

UPDATE: I am trying to match up the values of two form fields that are being passed. If `form.sched` contains `form.bldgarea`, output the values of both. It is erroring out stating it can't find anything at position 4. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#arrayLen(form.bldgarea)#">

   <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#arrayLen(form.sched)#">

      <cfif #form.sched[i]# contains #form.bldgarea[i]#> 
        <cfoutput>
            #form.sched[i]#, #form.bldgarea[i]#          
         </cfoutput>
      </cfif>

    </cfloop>

</cfloop>
```

Comment: Hint: See the [cfloop: looping over a list, a file, or an array](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-j-l/cfloop-looping-over-a-list-a-file-or-an-array.html) documentation.

Comment: They two fields do not have the same number of values/elements.  What type of form fields are they: text, checkbox, ...?

Comment: One is a checkbox with an output of a query as the value. The other is a dopdown select box . So if all goes as planned here is what I am trying to achieve:

      91_Hall1, hall1

Comment: (Edit) Hmm... so the ultimate goal is to extract the selected `sched` value only when the associated `bldgarea` box is checked? Does the query contain some sort of unique identifier column, like an ID? If yes, I would suggest a different form field structure instead.  BTW, checkbox values are only submitted IF the box was checked. That is why the two field arrays have a different number of elements.

Comment: Yes the sched value is two fields concatonated. The sched id number which is a two digit number then an underscore, then the building name. So the sched ID and building name together are the key field. But since I am outputting a list of buildings and dropdown select boxes which results in tons of scheds getting submitted at the same time I am trying to figure out how to just get the first two digit sched numbers for the buildings in the form.bldgarea array.

Comment: Gotcha. Let me write up an alternative approach I think will better handle this case. Does the building query have some sort of numeric ID you could use instead of name? It is better to use numeric id's for field names when possible, so you do not have to worry about (possibly) invalid field names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

If you are getting an error on submit, I suspect you are running into the security feature added to CF9+ which [Limits the maximum number of POST fields allowed](http://web.archive.org/web/20160429073222/https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-security-hotfix.html). A simple option is to increase the limit in the CF Administrator.

Another possibility is to restructure the form. Move the select lists into a separate `<form>`, so they are not submitted. When the user clicks the submit button in the main form, use jQuery to build a list of the selected items and store it in a hidden field. Similar to the approach in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292607/put-checkbox-values-into-hidden-input-with-jquery). Then on the action page, loop through that received list of values.

---

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

> The ultimate goal is to extract the selected `sched` value only when
>   the associated `bldgarea` box is checked.

I would suggest a slightly different approach. Assuming you have some sort of (unique) *numeric* ID to represent each building, use that as the checkbox "value", rather than building name.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="bldgarea" value="#queryName.buildingID#">
```

Then use the building ID value to generate unique names for each of the select lists:

```
<select name="sched_#queryName.buildingID#">
```

When the form is submitted, `form.bldgarea` will only contain the id's of the selected buildings. Loop through that array and grab the associated `sched` value dynamically, using associative array notation.

```
  <cfloop array="#form.bldgarea#" index="variables.buildingID">

     <cfoutput>
        buildingID = #variables.buildingID#
        schedID = #FORM["sched_"& variables.buildingID]#
        <br>
     </cfoutput>
  </cfloop>
```

**NB:** Checkboxes are only submitted if something was checked. Be sure to verify `form.bldgarea` exists before using it.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am playing around with it now. Should I be specifiying variables.buildingID or should it be something else like the form field?

Comment: Yes, `variables` is more appropriate here since it is a local page variable, not something submitted via POST. (*Technically* you could copy the id's into the `form` scope if needed, but there is no real benefit to doing that)

Comment: If I change the name of my select to sched_#bldgarea.id# I get a message that says bad request when I submit. Not sue what is going on.

Comment: The name alone should not cause an issue normally. Not sure without seeing the actual code you used and error message. Do you have any error handling enabled? If you are in Dev, temporarily disable it so you can see the real error. Also, check your log files.

Comment: (Edit) Hm... how many form fields total? Later versions of CF [default to a maximum of 100 form fields](http://web.archive.org/web/20160429073222/https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-security-hotfix.html) as a security measure. The limit can be increased via the CF Admin for CF10+.  That might be the issue.

Comment: I have 998 fields going through. I would love to only submit the rows that are checked. I need to be able to do that with one button press though and not a separate form submit for each row.

Comment: Here is an example of what I am trying to do. [Example Image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/89363486/example.png) 

You can see that there might be many buildings available on the right, but I only want to submit the ones that are checked. I need to get the info from the left side as well as the building id and schedule id on the right. If there is a better way to do this I'm all for it.

Comment: *only submit the rows that are checked* You probably could, but only with some sort of javascript code. The method above is simpler IMO. I suspect the only reason it is not working is the [POST fields limit](http://web.archive.org/web/20160429073222/https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-security-hotfix.html) mentioned. So you could A) Keep current form and increase the limit or B) Use custom javascript code to limit the items submitted or redesign the form

Comment: For option B) one possibility is move the selects into a separate (secondary) form. When the main form is submitted, use jQuery to build a list of the selected items and store it inside a hidden field in the main form. The basic idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292607/put-checkbox-values-into-hidden-input-with-jquery .

Comment: Ok got it now! I did have to increase the post limit a little. Everything is working now and your above method is working great. Thank you for the help. I appreciate it.

Comment: One additional question with this. Everything is working great except for one thing. If more than one checkbox is selected it sends everything through as an array. If it is just one it sends it through as a string. Is there a simple way to make sure everything is sent through as an array?

Comment: Not sure why they implemented it that way.  I do not think you can force it, but you could do a simple `IsSimpleValue()` check on the action page. If true, you know it is not an array, so convert it to one ie `form.bldgarea = listToArray(form.bldgarea)`